# Frontend security - Is it possible to limit access scope?

Tags: javascript, security, frontend, webassembly, micro-frontend

Given the growing size of frontend code, the concept of micro-frontend and module federation provided by Webpack 5 is a possible solution. However, considering the possibility that you are integrating code from other teams / 3rd parties, the foreign code could potentially try to access information it's not meant to by simply accessing the `window` object and iterating through its children.

This doesn't have to be critical information like passwords and credit cards, which are often isolated using an `iframe`. Less sensitive information like user emails, or tracking data could be collected and misused.

In this case, is there any technical set up that doesn't involve `iframes` that could limit the access scope of scripts? Is this something that could technically be implemented inside a WebAssembly program?

**Edit**: Yes, the conservative rule is to simply not run untrusted code. The question posed however is if it's technically possible to sandbox frontend code without using `iframe` to limit its access to information.

Comment: There's one simple rule: don't load and execute code that you don't trust.

Comment: Don't put sensitive information on the client-side, don't use libraries, or other applications, that for one reason or another doesn't seem trustworthy (not supported by a well-known org/group, or doesn't have a big enough following etc.).

Comment: @Bergi Updated the comment on window - not calling but referencing. I would of course prefer to not run untrusted code but wondering if there is a way to sandbox untrusted code. Question of curiosity, and if not possible of course I won't be doing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Javascript is inherently "public", so at some point stuff you put in or get out will eventually be exposed, either through the network fetch/XHR, or through function execution.

There is a "private" pattern in javascript, which prevents snooping around inside an object -- where you explicitely define the methods/properties that are exposed:

```
window.myThing = (function(){

    var a = "a";
    var private_b = "b";

    function one(){
        return "one"
    }

    function private_two(){
        return private_b
    }

    return {
        public_a : a,
        public_one : one
    }

}());


for(var prop in window.myThing){
    console.log(prop, window.myThing[prop])
}

// ----------------------------------
// only the following properties 
// are exposed from the window scope:
// ----------------------------------
//  + public_a as - a
//  + public_one as ƒ one()
```

In theory, this type of pattern could allow for internal (non-exposed/non-traversable) methods and properties... and leverage some form of encryption for "ins and outs".

Comment: Right, never thought of function's variable scope in this way. Just to confirm my understanding, what you can keep "private" is locally declared variables inside functions?  In general scripts calling functions can only see their returned values?

Comment: True, functions have an isolated scope. (Review var let const for scope definitions.) "var" is isolated to the function { brackets } it is declared within (and children function/brackets -- parents can't "see" it). FYI: "let" is similar in nature, but isolated to if/for/while/etc brackets. There is no effective way to read a var declared within a function unless the function returns its value.

Comment: Hey @bob, I came upon Shadow DOM https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/attachShadow
Perhaps `mode: closed`: `Denies access to the node(s) of a closed shadow root from JavaScript outside it` could be used to segregate information?

Comment: Could be a good route, might want to look into web components too, which leverage Shadow DOM (ShadowRoot) -- which would add an extra layer. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Web_Components ... be careful with sensitive info though, "where there's a will, there's a way".